# Make image unclickable in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, click

So, I have a bunch of images that do things when you click, and a hand that moves around above these images. I'm using jquery to run a function when the images are clicked. The problem is the hand gets in the way of the images so the hand is clicked rather than the image underneath. I can put the hand behind but it needs to show in front.

Can I make jquery ignore the hand on click events? make it invisible to the mouse? unclickable?

Answer (score 3):

try applying the property [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) with the value set to `none` in the CSS of the hand image:

```
hand-image-selector{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this css for your hand element:

```
.thehand {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20pointer-events